# Setting a debug branch that can be updated along with master

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two branches *master* and *debug*. If I try to merge *debug* to *master* branch, it fast-forwards. So I use the following command to avoid fast-forwarding:

```
$ git merge --no-ff debug
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
file.txt |  117 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++-----------------------------------
1 files changed, 51 insertions(+), 66 deletions(-)
```

That still seem like fast-forward to me. How can I do merge manually? 
Since git is not behaving the way I want to, I am starting to wonder if my using git is wrong, or I am not following the practice that is expected by other developers.

I want to have one branch with all the debugging options, comments, and print statements, and actually makes progress on the code. After I get something working properly in the debug branch, I want to merge it to *master* branch just the working code, not the extra information for debugging. Is this a valid way to go about doing version control on git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merge resolves to fast-forward in your case simply because the branch "master" is fully contained in branch "debug" at the time you merge — that is, there simply is nothing to merge since there's no divergence.

Now the question is: how do you suppose to merge your debug branch into "master" so that it does not receive unwanted code chunks (those debug printout statements etc)?  Have you answered it for yourself already?  I mean, using `--no-ff` is a viable approach (some workflows even recommend always using it) but why are you not using `--no-commit` as well — to actually *delete the unwanted code before committing?*

In other words, it appears to me that you for some reason you decided this should work:

1. Have a "pristine" code in your "master" branch.
2. Fork a "debug" branch off "master".
3. Add some new code there, add some debugging code there.
4. Merge "debug" back to "master" and expect this operation to somehow only bring the non-debugging code in.

Obviously, this is not gonna work: Git has no way to know which code is okay to bring when merging and which one is debugging.

Comment: I agree with your last paragraph and 4 is false. That is why I want to do manual merge. I wanted to keep the commit on *debug* branch separate and `--no-commit` did the job for me. Thanks Kostix. But I would expect git to open up git difftool even without `--no-commit` to resolve the differences before committing, which ensures that no code gets left behind from the *master* branch, or give the developer a chance to glance over. You wrote "there's no divergence" - since there are insertions and deletions, isn't there a divergence? Why it is considered that there is no divergence?

Comment: @Forethinker, yours is a very philosophical question as it actually touches other questions like "what's a branch?", "what does exactly constitute a merge?" etc. Git developers codified *their* definitions of branches and merges, which are seemingly different from yours. I'm not sure where to move from this point... Git was created primarily to manage source code. Merging in Git tries to bring all *textual* changes from (an)other branch(es) into a current branch; a conflict is ever declared if these *textual* changes conflict (or there are file-level delete/modify conflicts).

Comment: @Forethinker, hence if Git sees that a branch to merge is technically just a plain continuation of a current branch, the current branch is just promoted to point to the merged branch tip commit ("fast-forwarding") because to bring all the changes in from that branch, there's no point doing true merge. So that's what Git *assumes.* If you *mean* your would-be-ff merge should not bring *all* the changes, you have to tell Git about this, using the `--no-commit` command-line option.

Comment: @Forethinker, note that in some sense doing such an edited merge you're breaking "the contract" as the result of such merge won't include *all* the changes from the merged in branch, which is *assumed by default.* There's nothing wrong with this approach, but you should understand what you're doing.

Comment: @Forethinker, and regarding "no divergence"... It should be stressed that the divergence as far as Git is concerned happens when *both* branches to be merged one into another has been modified (received their respective commits each) since their branching point -- effectively creating "a fork". This is *the* divergence.